# Eth 2 staking - Required mainet recent blocks

Tags: warp-sync, openethereum, staking

How many recent ethereum 1 mainet blocks does ethereum 2 staking clients need?

I am syncing eth 1 mainet with OpenEthereum (Parity) and saw that I could change the --warp-barrier to 11500000 which is around 40000 blocks from the most recent block.

Also are the states stored from 'warp-sync' smaller than not using warp? In that case it would be beneficial to every now and then resync with warp set to the recent blocks so you can save space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gathered I can say:

- Warp syncing became to complex so it is no longer made after ~1,000,000 blocks I think
- Warp syncing takes the same amount of storage as normal syncing, only warp syncing is much faster since you download snapshots then to the executions later.